# MOSFET high-side 12 VDC switch lets the "magic smoke" out of my D1 Mini

Tags: mosfet, switches, esp8266, high-side

Edit: I don't know if it's better to post an answer myself or add this comment here, but thanks to the comments from @Ale..chenski and @KevinWhite I realised that the problem was not with the MOSFETs but with the power supply. Using 2 separate power supplies (and a new D1 Mini and a new RGB LED, since both were fried) solved the problem.

TL;DR: what's wrong with the attached schematic? With only the USB 5 VDC power connected all the little "peripherals" worked fine, but as soon as I connected the 12 VDC line (and its ground) for the fans, the "magic smoke" came out of the D1 Mini voltage regulator.

[image: circuit schematic]

The details:

I made a circuit to control 12 VDC PWM fans using two MOSFET transistors, based on the temperature read by an ESP8266 D1 Mini from a couple of DS18B20 sensors. I also added other components like a capacitive button, a buzzer, a red LED, and an RGB LED to allow me to add more features.

I used an ESP8266 because of these other features and also because I want to monitor and control this circuit from Home Assistant. The HA integration part is working fine, I don't need any help with that; I need help with the schematic itself.

The fans are running on 12 VDC and are each rated for 0.2 A. They have their own built-in PWM controller, which is working fine, except for one thing: it can't completely turn off the fans. The whole point of the circuit is to minimise noise, as the fans will operate in my living room, so if the temperature doesn't warrant the fans working then I would like them to be completely off.

I used both an N-channel and a P-channel MOSFET because I wanted a high-side switch, because I [read on GitHub](https://github.com/3ative/PWM-Fan-controller/issues/2) about issues when using a low side switch - the fans would keep running with just the PWM line and the 12 V line, likely using the PWM line as some sort of ground when the link to the real ground is cut off. I thought it would be simpler to use an extra transistor rather than an optocoupler as described on GitHub. I guess I could have used a BJT instead of the N-channel MOSFET, but I thought using a MOSFET would reduce the power drawn from the GPIO pin.

My thinking was: if I cut the 12 V line going to the fans to turn them off instead of cutting the ground then it would be very unlikely that they would keep spinning.

I first tested the MOSFET switch on a breadboard and it worked fine - it turned the fans on and off as expected, depending on whether I applied +3 V from 2 AA batteries to the gate of the N-channel MOSFET.

I then built the PCB with all bells and whistles. I tested everything except the MOSFET switch using just the USB 5 VDC power connected and all worked great. However, the moment I connected the 12 VDC line and its ground the voltage regulator on the D1 Mini module gave up the ghost.

The 12 VDC came from the same USB charger as the 5 VDC - it has both a USB A socket (which provides the 5 VDC via the USB port on the D1 Mini) and a USB type-C socket, from which I get the 12 VDC via one of those small [PDC004-PD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006323268960.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.60af38dauaTcWX&mp=1) PD "Decoy" modules. I thought this would be a good idea because I wouldn't have to use a buck converter, keeping the PCB simpler, avoiding the switching noise right next to the ESP8266, and also improving power efficiency.

I tested the MOSFET switch on the PCB again using the +3 V from batteries and it's still working. The D1 Mini is obviously not working anymore since its voltage regulator is charred.

Could anybody please give me a steer?

Comment: what's wrong with the attached schematic? - it does not show real power supplies. To start, get a 5V source and a 12V source from reputable AC-DC adapters (of from a bench power supply), and try. To me, the "same PD USB charger" looks very suspicious.

Comment: Can the USB charger provide both 12V and 5V simultaneously or is the USB-A socket fed from the same supply as the USB-C?  The USB-A 5V may go to 12V when commanded by the Decoy module on the USB-C side.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks, I also thought about that possibility... but I dismissed it (maybe too soon) on the premise that it would probably damage anything connected to the USB A socket that can't handle more than 5V. Now that I see somebody else thought about the same possibility let me try to measure what happens to the voltage on the USB A socket when the PS decoy asks the USB Type C socket for 12V. I'll revert shortly with the answer.

Comment: @KevinWhite, Yeap, that seems to be the case, at least without any load both the USB A and the USB Type C sockets put out +12V! At least I now have hope there's nothing wrong with the circuit. Onto soldering pins on another D1 and using 2 chargers (one for +5V, the other for +12V), to avoid the same scenario. I'll revert once I'm done

Comment: @KevinWhite Meanwhile, is there any chance that the tachometer signal from the fans could be at 12V and damaged the D1 Mini, even with the R4-R7 resistors? Just want to get this thought out of my mind, one way or another :) (the fans are Thermalright TL-C12C). Thanks

Comment: @Dan - the tachometer outputs I've seen from fans are of open collector type that would not send out 12v. Also the 3.3k resistor in series that would prevent any damaging currents getting to the MCU.

Comment: The alarm signal circuit is not ideal as it will only output about 2.5V. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: OK, so I plugged in a new D1 Mini and using 2 separate USB chargers it now works as expected, including the tachometer input. I wish I considered doing this (i.e. using 2 separate chargers) from the beginning, it would have saved me almost an entire day. You are right about the alarm, too, that's what happens when one (me) is a beginner :) Thanks for pointing it out, I was wondering why it was so faint. Is there a simple way of making a small change to deliver 5V instead of 2.6V, while keeping the same NPN BJT?